# In SQL Server, null = null returns false (Even when SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I tried below code. Still same results no matter we set `ansi nulls to on or off`.

```
create table A
(
id int identity not null,
name varchar null
)

create table B
(
id int identity not null,
name varchar null
)

insert into A (name) values ('a')
insert into B (name) values ('b')
insert into A (name) values (null)
insert into B (name) values (null)

set ansi_nulls off
select A.name, B.name from A join B on A.name = B.name

set ansi_nulls on
select A.name, B.name from A join B on A.name = B.name
```

Result Set:
 --None--

Both seems to be returning empty rows.

If I do a `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, it should compare `null=null` and return true, Correct?

Can anyone tell Why no results are returned?

Comment: [SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks Martin. For the past two days, I am looking out for a real life example in understanding the correct usage of `set ansi_nulls off`.. Can you kindly provide me any ?

Comment: It's deprecated. There isn't a correct usage except not to use it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: So, If I understand correctly, going forward, the setting `set ansi_nulls ON` will be the default value ?

Comment: @ nowhewhomustnotbenamed. yes.